# get cookie, add new value und set it again with jquery and json values

Tags: jquery, json, cookies, setcookie

i try to make a list of favorit products. every product has its own id, it's the var productID and it's already accessible on any page. what i want to reach, is having a json-value in the cookie. after adding a new product, get the cookies value, add the new productID, an set the cookie again with the added value

{"0": "11","1": "17","2":"7"}

```
$.fn.memoProducts = function(options){

   options= $.extend({
      cookie_name: "memoProducts",
      cookie_path: "/",
      cookie_expires: 3,
    }, options);

function setCookie() {
    var cookieValues = getCookie();
    var cookie_value_add = [];
    cookie_value_add = cookieValues ? $.parseJSON(cookieValues): [];
    cookie_value_add.push(productID);
    cookie_value = JSON.stringify(cookie_value_add);
    var date = new Date;
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(options.cookie_expires*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = options.cookie_name+"="+cookie_value+"path="+options.cookie_path+";expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }

function getCookie() {
  if (document.cookie) {
     var values = document.cookie.split(options.cookie_name+"=")[1];
     if (values) {
        return values.split(";")[0];
     }
  }
  return false;
 }

$(this).click(function(e){
    setCookie();
});
}

$(function() {
    $("a.bookmark").memoProducts();
})
```

i don't know how to get it working. first error is: cookie_value_add is null. setting a cookie with only this:

```
cookie_value = productID;
```

works fine, but always overwrites the values set before. maybe somebody has got an idea...

Comment: This would be a lot easier for you if you just used the jQuery cookie plugin, instead of reinventing it.

Comment: ok it works now:   
var cookieValues = getCookie();
$.parseJSON(cookieValues): [];
cookie_value_add = cookieValues ? $.secureEvalJSON(cookieValues): [];
cookie_value_add.push(productID);
cookie_value =  $.toJSON(unique(cookie_value_add));

the rest is the same than before, i only added a funcion unique, to get unique values in the array